# Nutch without Solr & with MySQL:

Tags: java, mysql, ivy, nutch

I am new to Nutch, just setup using following url : [Nutch+MySQL](https://dcvan24.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/fetch-and-index-data-with-nutch-mysql-and-solr/)

I ran following command because the command mentioned in url is deprecated and not available with Nutch 2.3.

I ran the following command.
    bin/crawl urls 1 null 10

```
Injecting seed URLs
/home/Aayush/NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject urls -crawlId 1
InjectorJob: starting at 2015-03-15 17:14:50
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls
InjectorJob: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.gora.sql.store.SqlStore
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.getDataStoreClass(StorageUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:218)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
```

And I get the following error.

```
Error running:
  /home/Aayush/NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject urls -crawlId 1
Failed with exit value 255.
```

I found somewhere that Nutch + MySQL is not supported by Gora version 0.5 you have to downgrade the version to 0.2.1. I downgraded the version in ivy.xml and then removed the directory build and runtime. And again rebuild the project using ant.

After rebuilding and rerunning I still get the above mentioned error.

Please provide any information/help.

Thank you for reading.